# Need to change values in MySQL Database, having trouble with SQL language

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, wordpress

I'm developing a website and there is a lot of manual work I have to do (clicking pages and setting templates etc) so I thought why not automate it. I have logged into PHPMyAdmin and have located the places in my MySQL database that I want to alter.

It consists of two parts, being 'wp_postmeta' and 'wp_posts'. I have a text file with all the 'post_id' that I want to access as well as the content that I want to change the page to. I can convert this to an arrat if necessary.

```
SELECT * 
FROM `wp_postmeta` 
WHERE `post_id` =x
AND `meta_key` LIKE '_wp_page_template'
AND `meta_value` LIKE 'template-blank-4.php'

SELECT*
FROM `wp_posts`
WHERE `post_id` =x
```

What I'm trying to do is do a loop or else a series of if/else statements where  can access my post number and set its page content. I would perform the two actions (being setting the content and setting the page template) separately.
How do I start?

Here is an extremely rough eapmle of what I want to achieve;

```
Array =(1,2,3,4...1200)
Array2=("string1", "string2", "string3"..."string1200")
for (array[i], i<1200) {
SELECT*
from 'wp_posts'
where post_id=i
set post_content="array2[i]"
SELECT*
from 'wp_postmeta'
where post_id=i
AND `meta_key` LIKE '_wp_page_template'
SET `meta_value` TO 'template-blank-4.php'
}
```

Any help with this would be greatly appreicated

Comment: Have you already tried php mysqli or pdo extensions? With one of those you can simply connect to your database and do manipulations with it.

Comment: Accessing / manipulating the WordPress tables directly in most of cases is not a good idea. You should use the standard way with https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

Comment: you must create a loop within a loop

Answer (score 0):

Like Bvcm said in the comments you should not do this over phpMyAdmin, but use a PHP script. As it seems you want to do a data import, i think the [mysqli extension](http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli.query.php) is the easyiest way for you. There is no need to use WP_Query unsless you want to reuse this import within wordpress, e.g. a plugin.
If it is possible, put your ids and your content into one array:

```
$data = array(1 => "string1", 2 => "string2", 3 => "string3", ... 1200 => "string1200")
```

If you have done that, your PHP code could look like this:

```
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");
foreach ($data as $id => $content) {
    $query_posts = "UPDATE wp_post
             SET post_content = '".$content."'
             WHERE post_id = ".$id;
    mysqli_query($link, $query_posts);
    $query_meta = "UPDATE wp_postmeta
             SET meta_value = 'template-blank-4.php'
             WHERE post_id = ".$id."
             AND meta_key = '_wp_page_template'";
    mysqli_query($link, $query_meta);
}
mysqli_close($link);
```